# How to read a resource in one java package (osgi bundle) from within another

Tags: java

I have a resource file(abc.yaml) in package abc.test

```
abc.test
       src
         main
           resources
             abc.yaml
```

i want to read this resource from within another package(xyz.test.util.Utils.java).

xyz.test
     src
          main
              java
                 xyz
                    test
                        uril
                            Utils.java

I tried

```
IOUtils.toString(RestApiUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/abc.yaml"), "UTF-8");
```

Seems this is not feasible as it refers to the resources in xyz.test package.

Is there any way which i can get this done? Given that abc.test cannot have a dependency on xyz.test as xyz.test has a dependancy to abc.test

Comment: it is better to put all the resources in projectRoot/src/main/resource

Comment: In my idea project i have two modules. In one module i have the resource file in src/main/resource.  And i want to read that in the second module.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a class beside abc.yaml, let's say XY.java, and use

```
IOUtils.toString(XY.class.getResourceAsStream("abc.yaml"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This won't work because my abc.yaml and XY.java, in two different modules.